# How to convert a red black BST into an array?

Tags: java, data-structures, red-black-tree

I want to convert a red black BST into an array but something goes wrong and I can't figure out what.
Here is a snippet of code I used to do this:

```
public T[] toArray() {
    T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, count);

    inOrder(root, array, 0);

    return array;
}

private void inOrder(Node<T> node, T[] array, int i) {
    if (node != null) {
        inOrder(node.leftChild(), array, i);
        array[i++] = node.data();
        inOrder(node.rightChild(), array, i);
    }
}
```

After inserting numbers from 10 to 200 in ascending order, the output looks like this (I used preorder traversal to see if the tree stay balanced):

```
[80, 40, 20, 10, 30, 60, 50, 70, 120, 100, 90, 110, 140, 130, 160, 150, 170, 180]
```

But when I call `toArray()` method, I get this:

```
80 120 140 160 170 180 null null null null null null null null null null null null
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: What is the first output ? Its is not sorted, which I would expect from a red-black tree

Comment: @Dici to produce the first output I used preorder traversal. That's why it looks like this. I needed to know whether the tree keep balance which I could observe by calling `toString()` after inserting a node.

Comment: @RenatKaitmazov Why did you ping me?

Comment: Sorry, I did it accidentally.

Comment: Ok, the problem is you never update the value of `i`, or more precisely you do it locally and it does not affect the recursive calls. More details in rgettman's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like only the root and the right-most children are getting copied to the array.  Your `i` value is being changed in each recursive call, but it's not getting updated when the recursive call ends.

Let's say your tree is:

```
    80
   /  \
  40  120
```

Your array is of size 3.

Your first call:

- `i` is `0`.
- Recursive call to `inOrder` with the left child:

  - `i` is `0`.
  - Recursive call to `inOrder` with the left child, which is `null`.
  - Store the element `40` at element `0`, increasing `i` to `1`.
  - Recursive call to `inOrder` with the right child, which is `null`.
  - Return.
- Here, `i` is `0` still!
- Store the element `80` at element `0`, increasing `i` to `1`.
- Recursive call to `inOrder` with the right child:

  - `i` is `1`.
  - Recursive call to `inOrder` with the left child, which is `null`.
  - Store the element `120` at element `1`, increasing `i` to `2`.
  - Recursive call to `inOrder` with the right child, which is `null`.
  - Return.
- Return.

The result is `[80, 120, null]`.

Have each recursive call `return` the value of `i` back to its caller, so that `i` stays updated at all levels of recursion.

```
private int inOrder(Node<T> node, T[] array, int i) {
    if (node != null) {
        i = inOrder(node.leftChild(), array, i);
        array[i++] = node.data();
        i = inOrder(node.rightChild(), array, i);
    }
    return i;
}
```